# Ruby - strings operation

Tags: ruby, string

I have this simple helper:

```
def printe_result(data)
  a_var = ('<a href="http://'+data.a_value+'>A</a>' unless (data.a_value.nil? || data.a_value.empty?))
  b_var = ('<a href="http://'+data.b_value+'>B</a>' unless (data.b_value.nil? || data.b_value.empty?))
  c_var = ('<a href="http://'+data.c_value+'>C</a>' unless (data.c_value.nil? || data.c_value.empty?))

  return ...
end
```

`a_value`, `b_value`, `c_value` I am taking from database. If the values are strings,  I want to save them into the respective variable and then all variables return as one string with the values separated by comma, for example:

```
"<a href=http://a>A</a>, <a href=http://b>B</a>, <a href=http://c>C</a>"
```

How can I merge the variables only if they exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def printe_result(data)
  { 'A' => data.a_value, 'B' => data.b_value, 'C' => data.c_value }.map do |name, val|
    "<a href='http://#{val}'>#{name}</a>" unless val.blank?
  end.compact.join(',')
end
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that you're using Rails or have required ActiveSupport's core extensions, as that's where [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) comes from. If not it can be replaced with `val.nil? || val.empty?`. I assumed you have Rails because of the URLs & the database reference.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
 [[a_value,'A'],[b_value,'B'],[c_value,'C']].select {|(value, label)| !value.blank?}.
    map {|(value, label)| %q[<a href="http://#{value}">#{label}</a>]}.join(',')
```

Ought to do the trick: use select to eliminate pairs with blank labels, map to turn the label into the desired text and join to join the strings together.

Comment: It's a shame the syntax highlighter gets so confused on string literals.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i get your question right - you can use the `defined?(variable_name)` method to check if a variable has been defined.

I hope this helps!

Comment: `defined?` would not help in this case: https://gist.github.com/e76db37917284e30dbb8